# Extracting information about View from Bigquery auditlog

Tags: google-bigquery

I have created a Sink using Log explorer that pushes data to Bigquery. I can get information about tables by using the following query.

```
SELECT
    SPLIT(REGEXP_EXTRACT(protopayload_auditlog.resourceName, '^projects/[^/]+/datasets/[^/]+/tables/(.*)$'), '$')[OFFSET(0)] AS TABLE
  FROM `project.dataset`  WHERE
    JSON_EXTRACT(protopayload_auditlog.metadataJson, "$.tableDataRead") IS NOT NULL
    OR JSON_EXTRACT(protopayload_auditlog.metadataJson, "$.tableDataChange") IS NOT NULL
```

However, I am unable to find information about Views. I have tried

1. Audit logs https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs
2. And biguqery asset information https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/resource-name-format
   however, I am unable to find how to get the information about "View". What do I need to include? Is that something in my sink or there is an alternative resource name I should use?

Comment: Hi Avi,  If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well.

Comment: hi, @ShipraSarkar  I am still trying to use that. So far I still can't get the view information. I can get it from ```SELECT * FROM myDataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS;``` I will update you once I managed to get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like auditLogs treat tables and views the same way.
I made this query to track view/table changes. InsertJob will tell you about view creations. UpdateTable/PatchTable will tell you about updates

```
SELECT  
resource.labels.dataset_id,
resource.labels.project_id,
--protopayload_auditlog.methodName,
REGEXP_EXTRACT(protopayload_auditlog.methodName,r'.*\.([^/$]*)') as method,
--protopayload_auditlog.resourceName,
REGEXP_EXTRACT(protopayload_auditlog.resourceName,r'.*tables\/([^/$]*)') as tableName,
protopayload_auditlog.authenticationInfo.principalEmail,
protopayload_auditlog.metadataJson,
case when protopayload_auditlog.methodName = 'google.cloud.bigquery.v2.JobService.InsertJob' then JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(protopayload_auditlog.metadataJson, "$.tableCreation"),"$.table"),"$.view"),"$.query")
else  JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(protopayload_auditlog.metadataJson, "$.tableChange"),"$.table"),"$.view"),"$.query") end
 as query,
 receiveTimestamp

FROM `<project-id>.<bq_auditlog>.cloudaudit_googleapis_com_activity_*` 
WHERE DATE(timestamp) >= "2022-07-10" 
and protopayload_auditlog.methodName in 
          ('google.cloud.bigquery.v2.TableService.PatchTable',
          'google.cloud.bigquery.v2.TableService.UpdateTable',
          'google.cloud.bigquery.v2.TableService.InsertTable',
          'google.cloud.bigquery.v2.JobService.InsertJob',
          'google.cloud.bigquery.v2.TableService.DeleteTable' )
```

Comment: I modified a bit to add   JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(protopayload_auditlog.metadataJson,
          "$.jobChange"),
        "$.job"),
      "$.jobConfig"),
    "$.queryConfig"),
    "$.query")

Answer (score 1):

[Views](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views-intro) are virtual table which are created and queried in the same way as queried from tables. Since you are looking for Views in BigQuery which is setup as a logging sink, you need to create Views in BigQuery by using the steps given in this [documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigquery-utils/tree/master/views/audit).

Currently there are two versions supported, v1 and v2. V1 reports API invocation and V2 reports resource interactions. After creating the views, you can do further analysis in BigQuery by saving or querying the Views.

Comment: This is definitely in a good direction. In my case, I still don't get the views. So I am checking now if there is something missing in my sink. The query is still very useful. Thank you